# SQLiteConnection - "System.OverflowException", but working

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm using `SQLiteConnection` and `ObservableCollection` to search in a database and then return the collection in a `ListView` control. I am by the way new to wpf and c#, but learning.

This code is working, and doing exactly what I want, but that's not my problem. I'm not sure if it is the correct way to go about it.

```cs
using (SQLiteConnection connect = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=" + dbPath))
{
    connect.Open();
    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connect.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT " + cols + " FROM Files" + query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter ad = new SQLiteDataAdapter())
        {
            ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                ad.Fill(ds);
                using (DataTable dtt = ds.Tables[0])
                {
                    List<SearchResultItem> lst = dtt.DataTableToList<SearchResultItem>();
                    return lst;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I use to update the `ListView` control, and maybe the problem can be found here:

```cs
try
{
    List<SearchResultItem> files = SQLiteHelper.Search(search);
    SearchResultList = new ObservableCollection<SearchResultItem>();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        SearchResultList.Add(file);
    }
    this.DataContext = this;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

My problem is when reading the output console at runtime.
There I'm getting an Exception thrown, that I do not understand. It repeats X amount of times depending on how many rows that is returned.

This is showing in output every time I use the above code.
My application is working like I want it to, I just want to understand why it is giving me that message in console. Can someone kindly explain it to me, so I can learn why and maybe there is a better way to write the code? :)

Exception thrown:

> 'System.OverflowException' in mscorlib.dll

Edit:
I managed to find the root of the cause my self.
In my class `SearchResultItem`:

```cs
public int isize { get; set; }
```

Solution:
Changing the type to `long` or `double` if I suspect values too large.
Thanks for the info, Perkins.

```cs
public long isize { get; set; }
```

Comment: You have the code, so work with it to reveal details to help understand what's going on.  In other words, the code you removed was an auto-implemented property definition.  Put the property back and change its type to `object`, then code explicit `get` and `set` methods that outputs data values and types to a debugging log (i.e. output window) and catches exceptions.  Or change the type to `long` or `double` if you suspect values are too large.  If you suspect values "too big" then investigate values in the DB using a db manager tool, etc.  Also, does the isize db column allow null values?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do know that it is an auto-implemented property, because I put it there. prop, and then hitting tab twice.
I did not remove it, I just commented it. 

However, changing the type to `long` was the answer I was looking for, so thanks for that.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but your question specifically asked "why", yet the solution you posted only included a simple "what you changed".  Changing code based on what you "suspect" is not very robust.  My first comment included advice meant to prompt you to *investigate other details*, not just "change it to long and see if it works".  Did you actually inspect the database data?  Do you realize that files can be larger than a 32-bit integer can hold?  (For what it's worth, I said "removed" because your first edit said "removing", and commenting code is essentially removing it.)

Comment: Yes, im using DB Browser for SQLite, but the database I built using Autoit. I just assumed that I needed to write the property as type int. The `isize` is from FileGetSize in Autoit back when I built the database. In that scripting language using that byte size as an int works just fine. Still learning though.

Comment: At first I did not know what triggered it, since everything was working fine. I then noticed that some `isize` values was returned as 0 bytes, when trying to make the bytes more readable, which let me to comment out the `isize`. Now I know that files can be larger than a 32-bit integer can hold. Thank you.